# Where can I find Player's Option Hybrid Classes and Multiclass Feats?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I was thinking of creating PCs with combinations of the PO Classes.

> Examples:
>
> - Eladrin Sha'ir/Elementalist - Psion
> - Vrydka Binder/Blackguard - Vampire
> - Halfling Rogue/Executioner

Are there any published or tested and balanced homebrew Hybrid Classes and Multiclass Feats of the PO Classes that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

#### Many of the final classes that were published never received hybrid classes or multiclass feats.

With the exception of the Hybrid [shadow] Assassin (Dragon 385) and the Hybrid Executioner (Dragon 400), all published hybrid classes are found in either Player's Handbook 3 or Dragon 402. No hybrid classes were ever published for the Elementalist or Sha'ir.

The same is largely true for multiclass feats. Dragons 400 & 402 have the multiclass feats for most of the post-PHB3 classes that ever got multiclass feats. After that, any class that didn't get a multiclass feat in the book it was published in (like the Sha'ir and Elementalist) doesn't have one.